# Google AppEngine complex WHERE condition

Tags: python, google-app-engine, where-clause, gql, gqlquery

I want to have a condition something like

- start_time <= start_time_input <= end_time
- OR
- start_time <= end_time_input <= end_time
- OR
- (start_time_input <= start_time AND end_time <= end_time_input )

The 2 ways as identified in the docs ( http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html and http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html)as I understood are :

filter_trips = db.GqlQuery("SELECT **key** FROM Trips WHERE ( start_time <= :start_time_input AND end_time >= :start_time_input ) OR (start_time <= :end_time_input AND end_time >=:end_time_input ) OR ( start_time >= :start_time_input  AND   end_time <= :end_time_input )" , start_time_input = start_time_input , end_time_input = end_time_input )

error: Parse Error: Invalid WHERE Identifier at symbol (

OR

filter_trips = db.GqlQuery("SELECT **key** FROM Trips WHERE start_time <= :start_time_input <= end_time OR start_time <= :end_time_input <= end_time OR (:start_time_input <= start_time AND   end_time <= :end_time_input )" , start_time_input = start_time_input , end_time_input = end_time_input )

error: Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol <=

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GQL doesn't have an OR. See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html

You'll need to do this as multiple queries.

Comment: KK i understood that , but why the error **Expected no additional symbols at symbol <=** ?

any error with that part??

Comment: Ok, so 

`("SELECT __key__ FROM Trips WHERE start_time <= :start_time_input <= end_time" , start_time_input = start_time_input , end_time_input = end_time_input )` query also gives me **BadQueryError: Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol <=**

Comment: @Gaurav `a < b < c` is not a valid expression in GQL. GQL syntax is documented at the pages you linked to.

Comment: @nick hmm read that.....Basiclly read that as a method of comparison for python.... Now how do I simulate the condition, as I can use inequality only for one field in an appengine

Comment: @Gaurav b >= a AND b < c is equivalent.